# Mockito expects() not throwing an exception

Tags: python, mockito

Mockito expects() function not throwing exception

I'm using mockito to test that KafkaProducer sends once with this line:
expect(KafkaProducer, times=0).send(...)
When times=2, a VerificationError is thrown in the console and the test fails, however when times=0 and InvocationError is thrown (seen through pdb but not the console), but the program continues normally with the test passing.

```
expect(KafkaProducer, times=2).send(...)

# Instantiates a KafkaProducer and calls .send()
send_to_kafka()


# Verify that send was called twice
verifyNoUnwantedInteractions()
```

With the expected to be 0, it passes pytest but throws an error when I walk through with pdb.

```
ERROR: 
Wanted times: 0, actual times: 1 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juswei/cosmosx/collectors/breeze/src/kafka_interface.py", line 46, in push_breeze_runs
    'BREEZE-COLLECTOR-TOPIC', data.encode(), timestamp_ms=timestamp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/mocking.py", line 88, in new_mocked_method
    self, method_name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/mocking.py", line 44, in remembered_invocation_builder
    return invoc(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/invocation.py", line 162, in __call__
    matching_invocation.should_answer(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mockito/invocation.py", line 309, in should_answer
    % (verification.wanted_count, actual_count))
mockito.invocation.InvocationError: 
Wanted times: 0, actual times: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing because you say you expect the Producer calls `send` *once*, but then use `times=0` which means never.

Generally:

```
In [35]: m = mock()

In [36]: expect(m, times=0).foo()
Out[36]: <mockito.invocation.AnswerSelector at 0x13b36b8>

In [37]: verifyNoUnwantedInteractions(m)

In [38]: m.foo()
<snip>
InvocationError:
Wanted times: 0, actual times: 1
```

t.i. if you want *never*, `foo()` throws `InvocationError`.

And when you **want** *once* you may get

```
In [39]: m = mock()

In [40]: expect(m, times=1).foo()
Out[40]: <mockito.invocation.AnswerSelector at 0x5017130>

In [41]: verifyNoUnwantedInteractions(m)
<...>
VerificationError:
Wanted but not invoked:

    foo()

Instead got:

    Nothing
```

t.i. a `VerificationError`. (If you would have called `foo` twice you again receive an `InvocationError`.) Which error you get is simply: Does it throw using a `verify*` function, or does it throw in the code under test exactly when calling the mocked function?

This can get tricky, if the system under test is actually in a separate thread, or in general is eating all errors.  Because then any exception thrown within this system can be handled for you, in the end it might just get logged and the test magically passes. But that depends on the system your testing.

But if so, it might be better to have lax/none expectations upfront, and then only verify in the test code.

```
when(Producer).send(...)  # <-- ... = anything is okay
testtest()
verify(Producer).send('foo', 'bar')  # <-- as specific as needed
```